# why aarch64 force qword aligned even transferred size is dword?

Tags: xcode, assembly, gnu-assembler, arm64

Below assembler code will cause "exc_bad_access code=259" on Xcode6.1.1 target on iPad air2.

```
    // SP default 16 aligned on function entry,
    sub sp,sp,#8
    st1 {v8.1d},[sp],#8
```

while new version will not

```
    sub sp,sp,#16
    st1 {v8.1d},[sp],#8
```

I find ARMv8_ISA document mention "aligned" on

chapter $3:unaligned address are permitted for most loads and stores,including...SIMD registers
chapter $5.8.24.1:...a post-increment immediate offset,if present, must be 8/16/24/32/48/64, depending on the number of elements transferred.

Above code transferred size is dword(8bytes),why forcing qword aligned? BTW, I had not tested it on Android ndk r10, so I'm not confirm it's restrict on aarch64 or Xcode?
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is the "st1" instruction that causes the crash?

You may check this using the following code:

```
sub sp,sp,#16
st1 {v8.1d},[sp],#16
```

I had a similar problem on x64; there it was another instruction which needed a properly aligned stack and caused the crash.

--- Edit ---

Sorry. I confused "[sp, #16]" and "[sp], #16".

If "[sp], #16" is post-increment then the test should look like this:

```
sub sp,sp,#16
st1 {v8.1d},[sp,#8]
add sp,sp,#8
```

Or:

```
sub sp,sp,#8
st1 {v8.1d},[sp]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While aarch64 requires "the post-increment by #imm must equal to the bytes to/from memory". so 'st1 {v8.1d},[sp],#16' can't pass compiling, the appropriate version is 'st1 {v8.2d},[sp],#16'. Can you help to share me more about the X64 case, it maybe helpful to distinguish whether it's a similar/different case.